# Android - Youtube video using WebView in ListView gets removed when i scroll out of view

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a ListView and in the cells displays youtube videos using a WebView, but when i scroll away from the youtube video, the youtube video gets removed from the cell when i scroll back.

Here is the code i am using (Custom ArrayAdapter):

In getView() method:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    /**
     * Created by xxx on 21/02/16.
     */
    public class MessageArrayAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<MessageObj> {


        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        public ArrayList<MessageObj> data = null;

        public MessageArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<MessageObj> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        //WeatherHolder holder = null;
        MessageHolder m = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            //TextView tv = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.threadTitle);
            //t = new ThreadObj(tv.getText().toString());

            m = new MessageHolder();
            //holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            m.messageUsernameTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.messageUsername);
            m.messageDateTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.messageDate);
            m.userImageLL = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
            m.messageTV = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.message);
            m.messageFlagIV = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.messageFlag);
            m.messageModIV = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.messageMod);
            //m.youtubeWV = (WebView)row.findViewById(R.id.youtubeWV);
            m.youtubeLL = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.youtubeLL);

            row.setTag(m);
        }
        else
        {
            m = (MessageHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        MessageObj message = data.get(position);
        m.messageUsernameTV.setText(message.firstname + " " + message.lastname);
        m.messageDateTV.setText(message.date);
        m.messageTV.setText(message.message);

        m.youtubeLL.removeAllViews();

        if(message.youtube.length() > 0){

            String frameVideo = "<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"></head><body><iframe width='100%'  src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + message.youtube + "' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

            WebView youtubeWV = new WebView(context);


            youtubeWV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
            });
            WebSettings webSettings = youtubeWV.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            youtubeWV.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
            m.youtubeLL.addView(youtubeWV);
        }else{

            m.youtubeLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //m.youtubeWV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }



        if(message.countFlags > 0){
            //t.threadFlagIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag2);
        }else{
            //t.threadFlagIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag1);
        }

        if(message.isMod){
            //t.threadFlagIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag2);
        }else{
            //t.threadFlagIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag1);
        }

        if(message.userImageId == 1){
            m.userImageLL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }

        return row;
        }

        static class MessageHolder
        {
        //ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView messageUsernameTV;
        TextView messageDateTV;
        LinearLayout userImageLL;
        TextView messageTV;
        ImageView messageFlagIV;
        ImageView messageModIV;
        //WebView youtubeWV;
        LinearLayout youtubeLL;
        }
    }
```

If you want me to add more code, i will do so.

Comment: It is not advisable to use a scrollable view inside a parent scrollable View. Adding a webView inside a ListView for example.

Comment: NollyJ: Thanks for replying, but i don't understand what you replied

Comment: Can you please add the full adapter class? Looks like your `m.youtubeLL.setVisibility(View.GONE);` removes the view, is it properly restored `m.youtubeLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` ?

Comment: xAF: i tried restoring the visibility but still no luck

Comment: Did you try adding `m.youtubeLL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` under `m.youtubeLL.addView(youtubeWV);`?

Comment: xAF: Yes and no luck

Comment: How about this: do not initiate (also add, remove conditionaly) new WebView, but instead reuse previous one, while loading different data? Also, are you completely sure the view does not exist and it's not an issue of WebView?

Comment: xAF: What if i create a separate layout for cell calling it message_item_cell_youtube.xml and if youtube.length > 0 then pass in that layout resource xml file, will that work?

Comment: It might, but if you would ask me for a recommendation on this case, the only problem I see with your code is an amount of WebView initiations. In my experience it is a very problematic component. Check out [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/), I think this would work better for you